# Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい(Mac)

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, anaconda3

MacからAnaconda3をアンインストールしたく、調べながら下記アンインストールの手順を辿ったのですが、アンインストール出来ていないようです。

1. ターミナルでconda install anaconda-cleanを実行
2. anaconda-cleanを起動して全てにyesと回答
3. ホームディレクトリ直下にあるAnaconda3フォルダ、ユーザー/〇〇(ユーザー名)にあるAnacondaProjectフォルダを削除

4.bash_profileの中のPATHを削除しようと思いましたが、

---

export PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"
export PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

---

のみで #added by anaconda の部分がありませんでした。

ここまできてPCを再起動してターミナルでpythonを実行すると

---

Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:30:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

---

と出てきます。Anacondaのアンインストールが出来ていないと思われます。
完全にアンインストールするには、後は何をすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: ターミナルで `type python` を実行するとどう表示されますか？

Comment: python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)と表示されます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyenv versions で、今ローカルにインストールされている python のバージョンを確認し、(おそらく anaconda 系になっていると思われる)

pyenv global system などで、利用する python バージョンを、アンインストールしたい anaconda 以外のものを指定します。

最後に、

```
pyenv uninstall アンインストールしたいanacondaのバージョン
```

を実行すると、 anaconda をアンインストールできると思います。

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で無事アナコンダをアンインストールできました。